# Significance of ConcurrentMap in Java

Tags: java

When the `ConcurrentMap` interface was first introduced, it provides some extra "complicated" action so that some common multi-step action can be made atomic.

However, `Map` interfaces seems absorbed all such kind of methods in `ConcurrentMap` as in Java 8.

What is the significance and use of `ConcurrentMap` interface in Java now?

Comment: "all such"--which, specifically?

Comment: @chrylis : In Java8, there is no method that exists only in `ConcurrentMap` but not `Map`.  In the past, there used to be things like `putIfAbsent()` that exists only in `ConcurrentMap` but now they are all in `Map`

Answer (score 2):

[ConcurrentMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) **is** guarantee about synchronization or atomicity:

> A Map providing thread safety and atomicity guarantees.

[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) **isn't** guarantee about synchronization or atomicity:

> The default implementation makes no guarantees about synchronization or atomicity properties of this method.

Also you can check and see that the default methods are different (as `merge`).

Comment: I am aware of such statement too.  So, now `ConcurrentMap` (if not considering the default method impl detail) serves more a documentary purpose rather than really declaring "concurrent map operations"?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the docs shared by [@user7294900](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294807/1746118) the `ConcurrentMap` provides a guarantee to synchronization or atomicity in its implementation. For example, the methods `forEach` is implemented as follows in both the interfaces :

***Map.java***

```
default void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entrySet()) {
        K k;
        V v;
        try {
            k = entry.getKey();
            v = entry.getValue();
        } catch(IllegalStateException ise) {
            // this usually means the entry is no longer in the map.
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException(ise);
        }
        action.accept(k, v);
    }
}
```

***ConcurrentMap.java***

```
default void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entrySet()) {
        K k;
        V v;
        try {
            k = entry.getKey();
            v = entry.getValue();
        } catch(IllegalStateException ise) {
            // this usually means the entry is no longer in the map.
            continue;
        }
        action.accept(k, v);
    }
}
```

While the former throws an exception on a modification to the Map where it is unable to access the entry anymore, the latter would continue to iterate over the rest of the entries available.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentMap represents a Map that supports concurrent access and guarantees atomicity i.e. you can get and put values in the map from different threads without risk of compromising data integrity. In particular,  it provides atomic `putIfAbsent`, `remove`, and `replace` methods. What does this mean?

Imagine you have a program with two threads accessing one map. Thread 1 calls `map.putIfAbsent("name", "Mike")` and thread 2 calls `map.putIfAbsent("name", "John")` at the same time. `putIfAbsent` should either return the value that was already there, or put the new value and return null. It works like

```
if (!map.containsKey(key))
    return map.put(key, value);
else
    return map.get(key);
```

But what if, just after executing the first line (and the condition is true), thread 1 is paused so thread 2 can run? Thread 2 will put it's value in the map before the program returns to thread 1, which still thinks the map has no value for name. So when it executes line 2, it sets its value but instead of returning null as expected, it returns the value thread 2 set, which should not happen.

This is called a race condition, and it happened because the execution of putIfAbsent was interrupted on thread 1 (i.e. putIfAbsent is non-atomic). But with ConcurrentMap, these methods are atomic and cannot be interrupted by each other, thereby eliminating such problems.

Comment: That's what I was meaning: things like `putIfAbset` has already been absorbed into `Map` ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V- ).  `ConcurrentHashMap` does not provide the "atomicity guarantee for complicated action" in the form of a specific method (e.g. `putIfAbsent`).  Although that's true that Map's `putIfAbsent` does not guarantee atomicity but that's more a documentary info, rather than "enforcing" by the interface design.